# Работа с data.frame без цикла

Tags: datetime, r, data.frame

Никак не могу сообразить решения без цикла.
Есть data.frame

```
+-------------------+-----------------+
| "key (ordered 1)" | day (ordered 2) |
+-------------------+-----------------+
| k1                | 01.02.2015      |
| k1                | 23.03.2015      |
| k1                | 01.11.2015      |
| k2                | 15.03.2015      |
| k2                | 16.08.2015      |
| k3                | 05.09.2015      |
| k3                | 10.09.2015      |
| k3                | 01.10.2015      |
| k3                | 01.11.2015      |
+-------------------+-----------------+
```

Надо по каждому ключу посчитать число дней прошедших до текущей точки и после. Для первых последних записей `df` - можно поставить `NA`.
То есть в результате должна получиться такая таблица:

```
+-----------------+-----------------+------------+-----------+
| key (ordered 1) | day (ordered 2) | day_before | day_after |
+-----------------+-----------------+------------+-----------+
| k1              | 01.02.2015      | NA         | 50        |
| k1              | 23.03.2015      | 50         | 223       |
| k1              | 01.11.2015      | 223        | NA        |
| k2              | 15.03.2015      | NA         | 154       |
| k2              | 16.08.2015      | 154        | NA        |
| k3              | 05.09.2015      | NA         | 5         |
| k3              | 10.09.2015      | 5          | 21        |
| k3              | 01.10.2015      | 21         | 31        |
| k3              | 01.11.2015      | 31         | NA        |
+-----------------+-----------------+------------+-----------+
```

UPD. Вот результат dput(mydata)

```
d <- 
structure(list(
key = c("k1", "k1", "k1", "k2", "k2", "k3", "k3", "k3", "k3"), 
day = c("01.02.2015", "23.03.2015", "01.11.2015", "15.03.2015", 
        "16.08.2015", "05.09.2015", "10.09.2015", "01.10.2015", "01.11.2015")), 
.Names = c("key", "day"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, образец данных, сгенерированный с помощью команды: `dput(mydata)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В своём решении я использовал пакет `data.table`, поскольку для меня он является наиболее удобным, а также показывает наилучшую производительность. По аналогии можно добиться похожего результата, используя функции из базового набора пакетов, или, например, с помощью пакета `dplyr`.

```
mydata <- structure(list(
    key = c("k1", "k1", "k1", "k2", "k2", "k3", "k3", "k3", "k3"),
    date = c("01.02.2015", "23.03.2015", "01.11.2015", "15.03.2015", "16.08.2015", "05.09.2015", "10.09.2015", "01.10.2015", "01.11.2015")),
    names = c("key", "date"),
    class = c("data.frame"),
    row.names = c(NA, -9L))
library(data.table)
mydata <- setDT(mydata)
mydata[, date := as.IDate(date, "%d.%m.%y")]
mydata[, `:=`(days.before = c(NA, diff(date)),
              days.after = c(diff(date), NA)), by = key]
mydata
#>    key       date days.before days.after
#> 1:  k1 2020-02-01          NA         51
#> 2:  k1 2020-03-23          51        223
#> 3:  k1 2020-11-01         223         NA
#> 4:  k2 2020-03-15          NA        154
#> 5:  k2 2020-08-16         154         NA
#> 6:  k3 2020-09-05          NA          5
#> 7:  k3 2020-09-10           5         21
#> 8:  k3 2020-10-01          21         31
#> 9:  k3 2020-11-01          31         NA
```